# segmentation fault signal handler sigint

Tags: c, signals, fork

I am trying to catch SIGINT (CTRL + C).
I want that when user type CTRL + C it will kill child process but the father process will continue normally.
when I have child process in my program it works ok, but when I have not child process, I get "segmentation fault".

I have done this:

```
void sig_handler(int signo);
//========================================
int main()
{
    // CTRL + C => SIGINT handler
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigfillset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    // Catch the signal
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
...
// done some checks and then fork a child.
} 

// SIGINT handler
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
 // dont know what to write here
}
```

Comment: before forking your child process get the current process ID, then fork it your child and get its process ID also then when handling the signal check whether ctrl c is for the parent process ID or not then implement your logic according to it.

Comment: On what line of code do you get the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that just by using the sigset() you can achieve your goal.

I would quote some information from man page of sigset.

> The sigset() function modifies signal dispositions.  The sig argument
>        specifies the signal, which may be any signal except SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.
>        The disp argument specifies the signal's disposition, which may be
>        SIG_DFL, SIG_IGN, or the address of a signal handler.  If sigset() is
>        used, and disp is the address of a signal handler, the system adds sig to
>        the signal mask of the calling process before executing the signal
>        handler; when the signal handler returns, the system restores the signal
>        mask of the calling process to its state prior to the delivery of the
>        signal.  In addition, if sigset() is used, and disp is equal to SIG_HOLD,
>        sig is added to the signal mask of the calling process and sig 's
>        disposition remains unchanged.  If sigset() is used, and disp is not
>        equal to SIG_HOLD, sig is removed from the signal mask of the calling
>        process.

Refer this link: [sighold, sigignore, sigpause, sigrelse, sigset — legacy interface for
     signal management](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man2/sigset.2freebsd.html)

You can establish a handler function that will be invoked when you get SIGINT.

```
void handler(int signo){
    // Here you can kill the child, if it exists
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     ...
     sigset(SIGINT, handler);
     ...
}
```

Hope it helps you, if you need more help, just mention it in the comments.

Comment: Please upvote, if the answer solves your problem.    --Thanks